# C - Why does returning an int result in a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I'm working on a small private project that reads some links from an html-page source. I read the html file line by line and then check if that line contains "data-cfsrc", which always preceeds a link that I want to read. This works fine, until I try to free the pointer that points to where the keyword ("data-cfsrc") starts.

I've tried freeing it on multiple points and it only works when I haven't done anything with it yet.

Here's my code:

```
            FILE *fp_w, *fp_r;
            fp_r = fopen("page.html","r");
            fp_w = fopen("bg_list.txt","a");
            char line[1024],img[512],c;
            //char *imgpoint = malloc(sizeof(char)*512);
            char *imgpoint;
            int i,imgcount = 0;

            while(imgcount<15){
                    // read line
                    i = 0;
                    do{
                            c = fgetc(fp_r);
                            line[i] = c;
                            i++;
                    }while(c!='\n');
                    line[i] = '\0';

                    if(strstr(line,"data-cfsrc") != NULL){
                            imgpoint = strstr(line,"data-cfsrc");
                            strcpy(img,imgpoint);
                            c = 0;
                            for(i=0; c!=34; i++){
                                    img[i] = img[i+12];
                                    c = img[i+13];
                            }
                            img[i] = '\0';
                            fprintf(fp_w,"%s\n",img);
                            imgcount++;
                            printf("imgcount = %d\n",imgcount);
                    }
            }
            fclose(fp_r);
            fclose(fp_w);
            //free(imgpoint);

            return 0;
```

EDIT: as mentioned, I removed the free() entirely, but now my program still results in a Segmentation fault when return is called.

EDIT 2: completely ommitted the impoint pointer. Everything still works, but I still get a Segmentation fault on return.

Comment: You’re modifying `imgpoint` at `imgpoint = strstr(…);`. | Looks like you have no reason to `malloc` or `free` it at all, actually, or even declare it outside the loop unless you’re stuck on C89 somehow.

Comment: Doing `imgpoint = strstr(line,"data-cfsrc");` you assign to `imgpoint` stack memory

Comment: If you call `free` on a pointer that has not been returned by `malloc` (and that's what you are doing here), you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: The variable 'imgpoint' seems not necessary in your code.
You can replace `imgpoint = strstr(line,"data-cfsrc");strcpy(img,imgpoint);` by `strcpy(img,strstr(line,"data-cfsrc"));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`free()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) requires you to pass the same pointer that was returned by `malloc()` (or friends). But here,

```
imgpoint = strstr(line,"data-cfsrc");
```

you are reassigning it. Hence *undefined behaviour* when `free()` is called.

From [`free()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html):

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, **which
>          must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc(), or
>          realloc()**.  Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called
>          before, undefined behavior occurs.  If ptr is NULL, no operation is
>          performed.

(emphasis added).